# Aligning column to bottom of page, and overlapping columns? (hard to explain, better description inside)

Tags: html, css, maps

I coded this page http://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/up206b/2014/MichaelSahimi/week2.html for one my classes. It has a column of text on the left and a Google Map and KML file on the right.

I'm a complete novice to coding and just started taking this class last week. My question is (and it could be a stupid one): Is there a way to have the left text column only occupy the bottom half of the page and have the right map column extend to the left of the page where the upper half of the left column used to be?

Basically, I want to make it seem like the text is floating over the ocean part of the map (which is why I made the background's color code the same as the water in Google Maps).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Below I have made some suggestions that should give you the desired effect. they are pretyy self explanatory.

```
#side_panel {
position: absolute;
width: 35%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
float: left; <-- remove this
padding-top: 300px; <-- add this
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
z-index: 5; <-- add this
}

#map_canvas {
height: 100%;
margin-left: 500px; <-- remove this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, you just want that map occupy the top half of page and and text appear on lower half. Am I correct?
I can see that the side_panel div is above that of map div in your html code. So move it below map div. Apply this css,

```
#side_panel{
   width: 100%;
   height:50%;
 }
#map_canvas{
   width:100%;
   height:50%;
   margin-left: 0px;
}
```